# How to type ü in Pinyin IME?

Tags: debian, gnome, keyboard, ibus

I'm using IME/iBus to type Chinese characters using Pinyin (Intelligent Pinyin 1.6.92 in Debian Jessie with Gnome 3.14.1). Now, I'm trying to type the word 旅行 (lüxing = travel), but all I get is 路性 (luxing), because it doesn't seem to recognize the two dots over the u, which makes ü.

Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/17450388#17450388)

It is Mac oriented. It says to try: nv

And says

> V is the standard convention to represent ü in pinyin input systems...

It refers to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinyin_input_method#Treatment_of_extended_Latin_cha%20racters_.28.C3.BC_and_.C3.AA.29) which says

> Since the letter "v" is unused in Mandarin pinyin, it is universally used as an alias for ü. For example, typing "nv" into the input method would bring up the candidate list for pinyin: nǚ.